# Why is the python built from source still showing the wrong version?

Tags: software-installation, python, compiling

I've downloaded the most recent tar from https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.10/Python-2.7.10.tar.xz, untar'd, configured, built and installed to a user directory.  I've also used those executables to configure a virtualenv environment.

However, running any of the new executables from their full path still only displays 2.7.6!

Here's a list of all python executables on the system and their versions:

```
sudo find / -type f -executable -iname 'python*' -exec file -i '{}' \; | awk -F: '/x-executable; charset=binary/ {print $1}' | xargs readlink -f | sort -u | xargs -I % sh -c 'echo -n "%: "; % -V'
```

yields:

```
/home/***/python2.7.10/bin/python2.7: Python 2.7.6
/home/***/Python-2.7.10/python: Python 2.7.6
/home/***/theano_env/bin/python: Python 2.7.6
/usr/bin/python2.7: Python 2.7.6
/usr/bin/python3.4: Python 3.4.0
/usr/bin/python3.4m: Python 3.4.0
```

I've done this twice now (once with 2.7.9) trying to solve a bug in flask that requires hmac on python > 2.7.7 but the correct versions don't seem to be installed.  Is there some magic I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to have these problems when configuring python with `--enable-shared` and the python executable would find and load the installed `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so`. Removing that option from the configuration helped solve the problem.

Comment: I appears that you are correct.  More info here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22157184/strange-python-compilation-results-with-enable-shared-flag

Comment: I never had the problem on 8.04, but only afterwards (ie. after running into problems with 10.04) realised that was because I compiled Python2.6 and the default python on 8.04 is 2.5(.2), so the shared libraries did not clash.